# How to print the count of value stored in an array using awk?

Tags: awk

I have this sample file -

```
$cat f
a a1
a a2
a a3
b b1
b b2
b b3
b b4
c c1
c c2
c c3
```

And to print the record side by side for a common column I used below -

```
$awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]OFS$2} END {for (k in a) print k ,a[k]}' f
a  a1 a2 a3
b  b1 b2 b3 b4
c  c1 c2 c3
```

How can I achieve below output in a single command, where last column is the count of record for a common column.

```
a  a1 a2 a3 3 
b  b1 b2 b3 b4 4 
c  c1 c2 c3 3
```

we can combine two command to achive this -

```
$awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]OFS$2} END {for (k in a) print k ,a[k]}' f|awk '{print $0, NF-1}'
a  a1 a2 a3 3
b  b1 b2 b3 b4 4
c  c1 c2 c3 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the return value of `gsub` - it returns number of substitutions made

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]OFS$2}
       END {for (k in a) print k a[k], gsub(OFS, OFS, a[k])}' ip.txt 
a a1 a2 a3 3
b b1 b2 b3 b4 4
c c1 c2 c3 3
```

Note: I've also removed `,` between `k a[k]` - otherwise there'll be two spaces between 1st and 2nd columns

Answer (score 1):

Another similar way to use would be to use `split()` on the field-separator to see how many fields are split with the de-limiter set. Also you need to get rid of the extra `FS` character when you generate the hash table as below

```
awk '{ a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS : "") $2 }
     END {for (k in a) print k, a[k], split(a[k],arr,OFS)}' file
```

But this involves a memory overhead of splitting the elements in the array `arr` which can be avoided in the `gsub()` variant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that expects the file to be sorted on the first field:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", ($1==p? "":OFS c[p] ORS $1), OFS $2;c[$1]++;p=$1}
       END {print OFS c[p]}' file

a a1 a2 a3 3
b b1 b2 b3 b4 4
c c1 c2 c3 3
```

It does print one ugly empty line before the output, though.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Sundeep's and Inian's answers, but with a slight touch :

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]OFS$2}
       END {for (k in a) { $0=a[k]; print k $0,NF-1 }}' ip.txt 
a a1 a2 a3 3
b b1 b2 b3 b4 4
c c1 c2 c3 3
```

This makes use of the feature that when you assign `$0`, it reparses it as if it read a new line and redefines `NF`.

> [`awk` POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)
>
> The symbol `$0` shall refer to the entire record; setting any other
>   field causes the re-evaluation of `$0`. Assigning to `$0` shall reset
>   the values of all other fields and the `NF` built-in variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method is to just keep count:

```
{a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2; c[$1]++}
END {for (k in a) { print k, a[k], c[k] }}
```

No reparsing, no substition, just a little extra memory.